# Problems assigning licenses with microsoft graph

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

My code follows what is indicated here

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_assignlicense

```
$datos=array("addLicenses"=>array(array("skuId"=>$sku)));
$this->graph->setApiVersion("beta");
$this->crear("users/$id_user/assignLicense", $datos);

public function crear($objeto, $datos){ 
    $r = $this->graph->createRequest("POST", "/$objeto")
        ->attachBody($datos)            
        ->execute();
}
```

Error

```
Type: GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException

Message: Client error: `POST 
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/USER_ID/assignLicense` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { 
"error": { "code": "Request_BadRequest", "message": "One or more parameters 
of the function import 'assig (truncated...)

Filename: /var/www/html/ischooldesarrollo/application/libraries/msgraph-sdk-
php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php

Line Number: 111
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3):

Couple of things:

1. Not that it's the problem, but why aren't you using [v1.0](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_assignlicense)?
2. The payload/body for the method requires 2 array parameters - `addLicenses` and `removeLicenses`. I don't see the second one. If you are just adding licenses, set `removeLicenses` to an empty array.
3. The `addLicenses` array is an array of [`disabledPlans` and `skuId`], with `disabledPlans` itself being an array.  If you don't want to disable any plans, just set this to an empty array.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I did what you told me,

`
$datos=array(
            "addLicenses"=>array(
                array(
                  "disabledPlans"=>array(),
                  "skuId"=>$sku
                )
            ),
            "removeLicenses"=>array()
        );
`


The error is now 404 not found, Request_ResourceNotFound

Comment: Sorry for the late response.  Can you add a trace of what is actually going on the wire please (i.e. the REST calls), and the full error response (i.e. not just the 404 but also the client request id and the timestamp please).